# Как по идентификатору сокета получить его тип, протокол...?

Tags: c++, сокет

Сервер принимает соединения и вызывает в потоке обработчик соединения, передавая полученный номер сокета в функцию обработчика:

```
int accept_socket = accept(serv_sock, NULL, NULL);
if( accept_socket!= WSAGetLastError() )
    std::thread(ConnectionHandler,accept_socket).detach();
```

Как по этому номеру сокета получить информацию о его типе, используемом в уже готовом соединении протоколе, заполнить `addrinfo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, чего Вы хотите, если честно.

Сигнатура функции accept:

```
int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

Передайте вторым параметром указатель на инстанс структуры sockaddr - и затем получите оттуда интересующую Вас информацию.

А Вы уверены, что это корректная проверка:

`accept_socket!= WSAGetLastError()` ?

Сравнивайте с -1.

Comment: да, точно -1. чего-то думал, что `accept` сразу код ошибки отдаёт. Ну то есть по одному идентификатору открытого подключения эту информацию не получить. Это и хотел уточнить. Спасибо

Comment: @Iceman, рад помочь!